# display only the content of a page in lightbox2 in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, lightbox2

I am using drupal.I have to display the content of a page in lightbox2.(only the content not header,footer,menubar,sidebar etc).The url of that content node is http://mysite.com/node/1.
I have included the lightbox2 module and used the below code

```
<li><a href="node/1/lightbox2" rel="lightframe[group|width:400px;][caption]">click here to see node content</a></li>
```

But the lightbox displays the whole page not only the content.i need only the text content.

Answer (score 1):

One more option in that you can pass a parameter in get method for `lightbox2` content.

Based on the parameter add condition in `page.tpl.php`

Answer (score 0):

Not the best of the solution, but achievable.

Create a new page.tpl for node/1 and print only $content in this.
this way you will make sure you only get content and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Vaibhav Jain, you can create a theme for the page without the header, left and right, footer. only the content and call that page inside the lightbox